# Problema com VSCODE

Tags: visual-studio-code

Olá.

Atualizei meu VSCODE hoje para a versão 1.65.1 e começou a apresentar alguns problemas.
O primeiro é esse contador:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele aparece no canto superior direito sempre que eu faço uma tarefa. E isso é realmente muito chato.

O segundo é sempre que eu digito algo toda a formatação do código fica alterando, a barra que indica o ponto em que digito fica assim também:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia!!

Eu consegui resolver o problema desinstalando o Vscode e apagando a pasta .vscode que no windows fica em AppData. Depois reinstalei e o problema acabou. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).